# Populate a data frame based on another one

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have a data frame (DF1) that I want to fill with values from another data frame (DF2) if the columns names match. If there's NA, or 0 I don't want to change DF1 columns but if theres 1 or 2, I'd like to modify with DF2 corresponding value.

Example:
df1

| sampleID | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | NA | 0 |
| B | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 2 | 0 |

DF2

| V1 | V2 |
| --- | --- |
| ID1 | 0.5 |
| ID2 | 0.7 |
| ID3 | 0.9 |

Desired result:

| sampleID | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | NA | 0 |
| B | 0.5 | 0 | 0.9 |
| C | 0.5 | 0.7 | 0 |

If there's a NA value, I don't want any change.
I've worked on an apply() + custom function based solution, but it's not working too well. Interested by any idea you might have. Also dplyr solutions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can use `sapply` + `replace`. Note that this works because IDs in `df1` and `df2` are in the same order.

```r
df1[-1] <- sapply(2:ncol(df1), 
       function(x) replace(df1[x], df1[x] != 0 & !is.na(df1[x]), df2[x-1, 2]))

#   sampleID ID1 ID2 ID3
# 1        A 0.0  NA 0.0
# 2        B 0.5 0.0 0.9
# 3        C 0.5 0.7 0.0
```

Or an equivalent solution with `match` (this one does not rely on ordering):

```r
sapply(2:ncol(df1), 
       function(x) replace(df1[x], 
                           df1[x] != 0 & !is.na(df1[x]), 
                           df2$V2[match(names(df1[x]), df2$V1)]))
```

Comment: Assumes identical col/row order in df1 and df2.

Comment: Indeed, this is what I mean by "this works because IDs in df1 and df2 are in the same order", and note that the `match` solution does rely on ordering

Comment: You're welcome! Also, @Vbokito, is there a reason why you have not [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) any answers to your [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8249244/vbokito)?

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve your problem:

```
df3 = df1
df3[df2$V1] = with(df2, Map(\(x,y) ifelse(x %in% c(0,NA), x, V2[V1==y]), df1[V1], V1))

  sampleID ID1 ID2 ID3
1        A 0.5  NA 0.9
2        B 1.0 0.7 1.0
3        C 1.0 0.7 0.9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Create a named vector
lut = setNames(df2$V2, df2$V1)
cols = intersect(names(lut), names(df1))
# [1] "ID1" "ID2" "ID3"

df1[cols] <- 
  lapply(cols, \(x) replace(df1[[x]], !(is.na(df1[[x]]) | df1[[x]] == 0), lut[x]))

#   sampleID ID1 ID2 ID3
# 1        A 0.0  NA 0.0
# 2        B 0.5 0.0 0.9
# 3        C 0.5 0.7 0.0
```

Data

```
df1 <- data.frame(sampleID = c("A", "B", "C"), ID1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L ), ID2 = c(NA, 0L, 2L), ID3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L))
df2 <- data.frame(V1 = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3"), V2 = c(0.5, 0.7, 0.9))
```